# How to check whether the sequence is in harmonic progression in python?

Tags: python, math

Harmonic progression is the series in which the consecutive terms differ by the reciprocal difference that of arithmetic progression. Take input as list of sequence return Boolean output.

I had tried using if and else statements. Looking for other alternative.

Comment: Please post what you tried, and explain how it was insufficient.

Answer (score 1):

First off, any harmonic series contains the reciprocals of another arithmetic series. So with the series we want to check, we can get the reciprocal of every item and check if that new series is arithmetic.

To check if any series is arithmetic we can use this function

```
def is_arithmetic(ls: list[int]):
    dif = ls[1]-ls[0]
    for i in range(1, len(ls)):
        if ls[i]-dif != ls[i-1]:
            return False
    return True
```

Now we have to just reciprocate our first sequence, then check if it is arithmetic.

Because floating point errors are very prone when dealing with reciprocals and fractions, I'm going to use the Fraction class from the inbuilt fraction module.

```
from fractions import Fraction as Frac
from math import lcm

def is_harmonic(ls: list[Frac]):
    # gets the numerators of each item in the sequence
    numers = [num.numerator for num in ls]

    # gets the denominators of each item in the sequence
    denoms = [num.denominator for num in ls]

    # this switches the two, "reciprocating the fractions"
    # of course the rest could be done without this but it's easier to understand
    numers, denoms = denoms, numers
    # we get the lowest common multiple of the denominators 
    multiple = lcm(*denoms)

    # gets every numerator as if every fraction had the same denominator (the lcm)
    for i in range(len(ls)):
        change = multiple//denoms[i]
        numers[i] *= change
    
    # we then return if these normalized numerators are an arithmetic sequence
    return is_arithmetic(numers)
```